# Pass Custom View Object from Controller to View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple problem. In my controller I take join of two tables and return like this:

```
data = ...
select new { Contacts = item, Applications = items, Answers = j }
```

This is working fine. I am getting what I want: e.g. 62 data objects with the attribues I want.

But in the view how do I access these set of data points?

simple `@model dynamic` is not working? There must be some way to do this.

Comment: You're providing anonymous type by `select` LINQ, what you're trying to achieve with that?

Comment: for custom object you can user Object Type

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I want results from all the 3 tables which I am joining that's why I used new {} ... all of those tables are part of the same model...so I create a db context object and just join the tables and return the tables' left join with new {}

Comment: @SunnyJangid where...in the view model?

Comment: Create a view model containing the properties your need and use `select new Youviewmodel { ... }` and pass that to the view,  not an anonymous object

Comment: You're mentioning 3 tables (implying 3 data model classes exist) but not include all of them. Try providing [mcve] by using viewmodel chosen to plot the query results into view.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to do that is by creating a ViewModel which will contain all the attributes that you need to display in your view.

```
 public class DataViewModel {
      public Contacts {get;set}
      public Application {get;set;}
      public Answers {get;set;}
   }
```

Create a list of your "DataViewModel"

```
List<DataViewModel> Datas = new List<DataViewModel>();
```

After doing that, you will have to assign the values of each element in your controller after getting them from your "data" variable that you created by simply using a foreach loop.

```
foreach (var instance of data) {
// Assign those values here
}
```

You'll have to pass the list of your data (ViewModel) to your view from your controller like this :

```
return View(Datas);
```

and to call the list of your ViewModel in your view like this :

```
@model IEnumerable<models.DataViewModel>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an 'umbrella' model like:

```
public DataModel
{
   public Contacts contacts {get;set}
   public Application  applications {get;set;}
   public Answers  answers {get;set;}
}
```

On controller:

```
select new DataModel(){ Contacts = item, Applications = items, Answers = j }
```

And have on View:

```
@model DataModel
```

Comment: I get cannoit implicity convert type to...dbset<type>

Comment: I think you mean `public Contacts Contacts { get;set };` etc

Comment: @StephenMuecke CS0029 C# Cannot implicitly convert type x to System.Data.Entity.DbSet<x> ....any way this could be resolved?

Comment: @RajeshRonaldo, You have not shown us the code that throws that error (but I assume you have declared the model incorrectly - it would need to be `IEnumerable<DataModel> data = ....select new DataModel(){ contacts = item, applications = items, answers = j }` in the case of apomene's model above

Comment: And you have not told us what the `type` of `item` and `items` and `j` are so you will need to adjust the view model types to suit.

Answer (score 0):

**Class**

```
public DataModel
{
   public Contacts {get;set}
   public Application {get;set;}
   public Answers {get;set;}
}
```

**Controller**

```
DataModel model = new DataModel();
model.Contacts  = items;
model.Application = item;
model.Answers= items;
return View(model);
```

**View**

```
@model DataModel

// will get all three tables data here

@Model.Contacts 
@Model.Application
@Model.Answers
```